# Water & salt liquid

Tags: problem-solving

If I'd have an $500$ ml bottle of water and it would have $1\%$ salt, how much I would need to add water to make it, lets say $0.3\%$? I cannot find the way to figure this problem. Could anyone provide the formula to solve this? Regards, TuukkaX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may think in the following way.

> In $100$ ml of water, there is $1$ gr of salt (this is what $1\%$ means).
>
> In $500$ ml of water, there are $5$ gr of salt.

Now, you want to add some water in order to obtain that specific percentage. The quantity of salt remains just the same. Let's say that we add $x$ ml of water. What we have is the following:

> In $(500+x)$ ml of water, there are $5$ gr of salt.
>
> In $100$ ml of water there are $0.3$ gr of salt (this is what we want).

Now, I think it is easy to find the unknown $x$.

---

Consider that these two variables are proportional. Thus, we have to solve the equation:
$$\frac{500+x}{100} = \frac{5}{0.3}.$$ Now, it must be easy to solve for $x$.

Comment: Could you make it more understandable, been doing math quite a bit here so I can't figure anything out now :P Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I need some sleep, huh.

Comment: I'm so confused right now. What is the answer? I see the formula but I'm using it in the wrong way. I calculated that the answer would be about 16.6667ml, but when I check salt%=5/516.6667*100 = not 0.3 :/

Comment: The answer is $x= 1166.67$ ml. Then,  $\frac {5}{500+1166.67}  =0.003=0.3\%$.